# Count number of categories after GROUP BY in SQL or Pandas

Tags: sql, pandas, oracle, group-by, pivot

I have a dataframe df :

```
ORDERID    PRODUCTTYPE  PRODUCTID  PRODUCT
123         Fruits         2       Banana
123         Vegetables     3       Tomato
123         Vegetables     3       Onion
321         Fruits         2       Grapes
321         Fruits         2       Avocado
```

I need output as

```
ORDERID  FRUITS  VEGETABLES
123       1          2
321       2          0
```

Is there any modification i need to perform to the groupby ?
I'm doing

```
df.groupby('ORDERID'['PRODUCTTYPE'].nunique().reset_index(name="count")
```

but thats just counting the number of categories

Comment: You need to pivot the group by. Please share your code so people can help you better.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, postgresql, sql-server...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of `groupby().value_counts()` and `unstack()`:

```
(df.groupby('ORDERID')['PRODUCTTYPE']
   .value_counts()
   .unstack('PRODUCTTYPE', fill_value=0)
)
```

Or `pivot_table`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='ORDERID', 
               columns='PRODUCTTYPE', 
               values='PRODUCTID', 
               aggfunc='count',
               fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
PRODUCTTYPE  Fruits  Vegetables
ORDERID                        
123               1           2
321               2           0
```

Answer (score 4):

In SQL, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    orderid,
    sum(case when producttype = 'Fruits' then 1 else 0 end) fruits,
    sum(case when producttype = 'Vegetables' then 1 else 0 end) vegetables
from mytable
group by orderid
```

Or, if your database supports the modern `filter` clause to aggregate functions:

```
select
    orderid,
    count(*) filter(where producttype = 'Fruits') fruits,
    count(*) filter(where producttype = 'Vegetables') vegetables
from mytable
group by orderid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
ORDERID,
count(Fruits) over (partition by ORDERID) as Fruits,
count(Vegetables) over (partition by ORDERID) as Vegetables
from 
table
group by ORDERID;
```

Comment: In Oracle, this would error like: `not a group by expression`. Also, there is no column `Fruits` or `Vegetables` in the table.

Answer (score 1):

One function in pandas `pd.crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.ORDERID,df.PRODUCTTYPE)
PRODUCTTYPE  Fruits  Vegetables
ORDERID                        
123               1           2
321               2           0
```